# Why are cookies necessary while we could use redux?

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, react-redux, local-storage

If I'm using react as frontend and node.js as backend...when a user logs in I  write the user name and user's info so as to persist amongst components. I also save his state which is logged=true. My question is ¿why do we need to save the token in a cookie (or a local storage) if the state of the user is saved in redux?? Is it necessary, couldn't I just use redux without storing it somewhere else?

Comment: If you don't use cookies then you won't know which user is which.

Comment: Don't persist any app state to local storage or cookie and see how well it works when the page is reloaded. Yes, you can use redux without data persistence, but how useful is that really?